# I'm trying to make a calculator but I keep getting CS0165 and I'm confused as to why

Tags: c#

The Console.Writeline(result); at the end returns error `CS0165 Use of unassigned local variable 'result'` and I don't know why. Would appreciate an explanation as I'm a complete beginner. Like I said in the title, I'm trying to build a calculator.

```
char Operator;
double firstNumber;
double secondNumber;

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the first number");
    string firstNumberAsText = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine("Enter the second number");
    string secondNumberAsText = Console.ReadLine();

    Console.WriteLine(@"Enter a math operation. '+' for addition, '-' for subtraction, '*' for multiplication, '/' for division, '%' for remainder and '^' for power");
    string mathOperator = Console.ReadLine();

    firstNumber = Convert.ToDouble(firstNumberAsText);
    secondNumber = Convert.ToDouble(secondNumberAsText);
    Operator = Convert.ToChar(mathOperator);

    double result;

    switch (Operator)
    {
        case '+':
            result = firstNumber + secondNumber;
            break;

        case '-':
            result = firstNumber - secondNumber;
            break;

        case '*':
            result = firstNumber * secondNumber;
            break;

        case '/':
            result = firstNumber / secondNumber;
            break;

        case '%':
            result = firstNumber % secondNumber;
            break;

        case '^':
            result = Math.Pow(firstNumber, secondNumber);
            break;

        default:
            Console.WriteLine("unrecognised operator: " + Operator);
            break;
    }

    Console.WriteLine(result);

    Console.ReadKey();
```

Comment: Please read our [ask] topics. You have to *precisely* specify *what* error (not only the error number but also the description) and *where exactly*.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit] your question to include your full source code you have and post the exact complete error message you get.

Comment: You never declare `firstNumber` or `secondNumber`.

Comment: I don't know what a CS0165 is off the top of my head. But I could probably tell you what the error means if you provided the text in your question, and I could help you faster. Always provide the error text in your question, not just the code.

Comment: @mason I made an edit explaining what the error meant

Comment: So "use of unassigned local variable", what happens if none of the cases match? What value will `result` have then?

Comment: @rufusL's answer is correct.  To see why, put yourself into the mind of the compiler.  It sees that you have declared `result` up above your switch statement.  And, it sees that you use it at the end of the switch.  Now it looks to see that no matter what happens, you have assigned it a value before you use it (at the end).  It sees that in every case - except the `default` case, you have an assigned variable, but, if the `default` case is chosen, it's unassigned.  So, it lets you know with that CS0165 (the actual order of the decisions I describe is different, but you should get the idea)

Comment: By the way, you will be much better off if you use `double.TryParse` rather than `convert.ToDouble`.  Always assume that anything a user enters has a good chance of being wrong.  `TryParse` will let you know if the entered value is a real double (so that you can tell your user "hey, enter a number")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error itself tells you what's wrong:

> Error CS0165: Use of unassigned local variable 'result'

This means that you're trying to use a variable that may not have been initialized yet. Notice that it isn't initialized it when it's declared, and it isn't assigned a value in the `default:` case in the switch statement.

So there are two ways to solve this:

1)  Initialize the variable when you declare it

```
double result = 0;
```

2) Or, make sure every possible code path (including then default switch case) assigns a value to it before it's used

```
default:
    result = 0;
    Console.WriteLine($"unrecognised operator: {Operator}");
    break;
```

Comment: This worked, thanks. Can you explain why it needs to be assigned a value in 'default' even though it's been assigned a value in every other 'case'?

Comment: Sure, because if someone enters an invalid operator, then none of the `case` blocks are executed (only the `default` case), so the variable is never assigned. But then the code execution still gets to `Console.WriteLine(result);`, which is an error (you can't use an unassigned variable). The compiler examines all possible code paths, discovers this specific scenario, and then gives you the error.

Comment: Another thing you can do is have a flag that there was an error and not output the result if there was an error (though you probably would still get the CS0165 - the compiler is smart, but probably not smart enough to pick up on logic like that).

Answer (score 1):

In the case of an unrecognised operator, the `result` variable would be undefined when trying to do the `Console.WriteLine()`. You either need to set it to a value when catching the default behaviour, or initialize it before the switch.